# Expected value of type "SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate" for association field

Tags: symfony

I get the following error:

> Expected value of type "SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate" for
>   association field
>   "SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimateDetail#$detail", got
>   "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" instead.

I'm trying to create a structure where there is a RequestForEstimate entity that may have multiple RequestForEstimateDetails nodes. Simply each row in the RequestForEstimateDetails will have a request for a different product and its details when RequestForEstimate only the common information. I'm new to Symfony and I struggle at the point where I want to save the parent element together with the children in the DB. I have been following this Symfony tutorial: [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)

Here is my code:

SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate:

```
<?php

namespace SourcingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * RequestForEstimate
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="request_for_estimate")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SourcingBundle\Repository\RequestForEstimateRepository")
 */
class RequestForEstimate
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="request_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="create_time", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createTime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="update_time", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updateTime;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RequestForEstimateDetail", mappedBy="detail", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $details;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->details = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param integer $status
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimate
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set createTime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createTime
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimate
     */
    public function setCreateTime($createTime)
    {
        $this->createTime = $createTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createTime
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreateTime()
    {
        return $this->createTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set updateTime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updateTime
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimate
     */
    public function setUpdateTime($updateTime)
    {
        $this->updateTime = $updateTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updateTime
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdateTime()
    {
        return $this->updateTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimate
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Add detail
     *
     * @param \SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimateDetail $detail
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimate
     */
    public function addDetail(\SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimateDetail $detail)
    {
        $this->details[] = $detail;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove detail
     *
     * @param \SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimateDetail $detail
     */
    public function removeDetail(\SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimateDetail $detail)
    {
        $this->details->removeElement($detail);
    }

    /**
     * Get details
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getDetails()
    {
        return $this->details;
    }

}
```

SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimateDetail:

```
<?php

namespace SourcingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * RequestForEstimateDetail
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="request_for_estimate_detail")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SourcingBundle\Repository\RequestForEstimateDetailRepository")
 */
class RequestForEstimateDetail
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="request_detail_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RequestForEstimate", inversedBy="details")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="request_id", referencedColumnName="request_id")
     */
    private $detail;
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $productId;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer")
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price_per_unit", type="decimal", precision=2, scale=0)
     */
    private $pricePerUnit;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="shipping_cost", type="decimal", precision=2, scale=0)
     */
    private $shippingCost;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="other_fees", type="decimal", precision=2, scale=0)
     */
    private $otherFees;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set product
     *
     * @param integer $product
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function setProduct($product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    /**
     * Set quantity
     *
     * @param integer $quantity
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function setQuantity($quantity)
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quantity
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    /**
     * Set pricePerUnit
     *
     * @param string $pricePerUnit
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function setPricePerUnit($pricePerUnit)
    {
        $this->pricePerUnit = $pricePerUnit;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pricePerUnit
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPricePerUnit()
    {
        return $this->pricePerUnit;
    }

    /**
     * Set shippingCost
     *
     * @param string $shippingCost
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function setShippingCost($shippingCost)
    {
        $this->shippingCost = $shippingCost;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shippingCost
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getShippingCost()
    {
        return $this->shippingCost;
    }

    /**
     * Set otherFees
     *
     * @param string $otherFees
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function setOtherFees($otherFees)
    {
        $this->otherFees = $otherFees;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get otherFees
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOtherFees()
    {
        return $this->otherFees;
    }

    /**
     * Set requestId
     *
     * @param \SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $requestId
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function setRequestId(\SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $requestId = null)
    {
        $this->requestId = $requestId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get requestId
     *
     * @return \SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate
     */
    public function getRequestId()
    {
        return $this->requestId;
    }

    /**
     * Set productId
     *
     * @param \SourcingBundle\Entity\Product $productId
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function setProductId(\SourcingBundle\Entity\Product $productId = null)
    {
        $this->productId = $productId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get productId
     *
     * @return \SourcingBundle\Entity\Product
     */
    public function getProductId()
    {
        return $this->productId;
    }

    /**
     * Set detail
     *
     * @param \SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $detail
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function setDetail(\SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $detail = null)
    {
        $this->detail = $detail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get detail
     *
     * @return \SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate
     */
    public function getDetail()
    {
        return $this->detail;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->detail = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add detail
     *
     * @param \SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $detail
     *
     * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
     */
    public function addDetail(\SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $detail)
    {
        $this->detail[] = $detail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove detail
     *
     * @param \SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $detail
     */
    public function removeDetail(\SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $detail)
    {
        $this->detail->removeElement($detail);
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace SourcingBundle\Controller;

use SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate;
use SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimateDetail;
use SourcingBundle\Form\Type\RequestForEstimateType;
use SourcingBundle\Form\Type\RequestForEstimateDetailType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class RequestForEstimateController extends Controller
{
/**
     * @Route("sourcing/request-for-estimate", name="request_for_estimate")
     */
    public function addRequest(Request $request)
    {

        $RequestForEstimate = new RequestForEstimate();
        $form = $this->createForm(RequestForEstimateType::class, $RequestForEstimate);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $request = $form->getData();

            foreach($form->get('details')->getData() as $detail)
            {
                $request->addDetail($detail);
            }

            print_r($form->get('details')->getData());
            $request->setStatus(0);
            $request->setupdateTime(new \DateTime());
            $request->setcreateTime(new \DateTime());
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($request);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('RequestsForEstimate');
        }


        return $this->render('sourcing/requestforestimate/create.html.twig', array(
           'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));



    }
}
```

My forms:

```
<?php
namespace SourcingBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class RequestForEstimateType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('details', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => RequestForEstimateDetailType::class,
            'allow_add'     => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,

        ));
        $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Request'));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate',
        ));
    }
}



<?php
namespace SourcingBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class RequestForEstimateDetailType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('quantity');  
        $builder->add('pricePerUnit'); 
        $builder->add('shippingCost'); 
        $builder->add('otherFees'); 
        // $builder->add('product'); 


    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimateDetail',
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `RequestForEstimateDetail` the getter/setter method of the field detail are for manage the collection itself (the add/remove methods are for the single element of the collection), so modify the getter/setter method to handle an `ArrayCollection` object.

As Example:

<kbd>RequestForEstimateDetail</kbd>

```
/**
 * Set detail
 *
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection an array of $detail
 *
 * @return RequestForEstimateDetail
 */
public function setDetail(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $detail = null)
{
    $this->detail = $detail;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get detail
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
public function getDetail()
{
    return $this->detail;
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you for your response but it hasn't changed anything. Still the same error. From what  I see you just modified the annotation of doctrine right?

Comment: Hi i suggest to modify the signature of the methods in order to accept an ArrayCollection object.

Comment: Could you please provide an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the existing addDetail method in the RequestForEstimate entity did the trick:

```
public function addDetail(\SourcingBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimateDetail $detail)
{
    $this->details->add($detail);
    $detail->setDetail($this);
    return $this;
}
```